# How to set password in LDAP using php?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

After successfully user creation, i am unable to login with username 
    and password. It show credential did not work. While i am entering 
    proper username and password.
    I have little bit knowledge of php. Please guide me.Thank in advance.

```
$username = "ntop\administrator";// ldap server username
$password = "******";// ldap server password
$ldap_server = "*.*.*.*";  ldap sever ip           
$name="sunill"; //common name
$email="sunil@gmail.com";
$pwd="mohdali@123456";
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);// ldap connectivity

ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die 
("Could 
not set LDAP Protocol version");

if($ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $username, $password) == true)
{ // if ldap bind

$adduserAD["cn"] = $name;// Common name
$adduserAD["givenname"] = $name;
$adduserAD["sn"] = 'Kumar'; // Surname
$adduserAD["sAMAccountName"] = $name; // SamaAccountname declare here
$adduserAD['userPrincipalName'] = $name;
$adduserAD["objectClass"] = "User"; // Object class user
$adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
$adduserAD['mail'] = $email;
$adduserAD["userPassword"] = $pwd; // set password here
$adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = "66080"; 
$base_dn = "cn=".$name.",ou=Netmetric,DC=ntop,DC=local";// base dn
// Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true){
echo "User is created";
}
ldap_close($ldap_conn);                
}else{ 
echo "Not connected with server";               
}
```

Comment: Try `ntop\\administrator` instead of `ntop\administrator`, seems like the a will be escaped.

Comment: user is displaying in Ldap but still unable to login